# How to properly call openssl_decrypt method if I have base64 string which contains from IV and encrypted data?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, rijndael, rijndaelmanaged

I have code in `C#` which encrypts and decrypts string:

```cs
private readonly UTF8Encoding _encoder;
private readonly ICryptoTransform _encryptor;
private readonly RijndaelManaged _rijndael;

public Crypter()
{
    _rijndael = new RijndaelManaged { Key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 16 } };
    _rijndael.GenerateIV();
    _encryptor = _rijndael.CreateEncryptor();
    _encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
}

public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
    => Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(_encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted)));
        
private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[] inputBuffer = _encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return _rijndael.IV.Concat(inputBuffer).ToArray();
}

public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    => _encoder.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)));
        
private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[] iv = buffer.Take(16).ToArray();
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = _rijndael.CreateDecryptor(_rijndael.Key, iv))
    {
        return decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 16, buffer.Length - 16);
    }
}
```

If you check `Decrypt(byte[] buffer)`, I take first 16 bytes which is IV.

Now I similar want to implement in PHP (imagine, that I will encode on `C#` side and send it to server which runs on php, where I want to decrypt it back). As the param to my PHP decrypt function will be output of C# `public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)`. I somehow need to get those 16 bytes to get IV and the rest part, which I respectively will pass as `$data` and `$iv` params to `$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($data, $cipher, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);` function

I have tried to use something like this (using unpack):

```php
$stringValue = base64_decode($encrypted_data, true);
$integers = unpack("s*", $stringValue);
```

and then tried to take 16 first numbers and somehow convert them back with pack method. But probably I have lack of knowledge.

Could you please help me with this?

P.S. This one I have tried based on Ilya's answer and comments.

```
$cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
$encryption_key = hex2bin(env("ENCRYPTION_KEY"));
$base64decoded = base64_decode($encrypted_data, true);
$iv = substr($base64decoded, 0, 16);
$data = substr($base64decoded, 16, strlen($base64decoded) - 16);
$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($data, $cipher, $encryption_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
dd($decrypted_data);
```

also if I debug code and check which bytes are in `$iv` using this code:

```
$stringValue = base64_decode($iv, true);
$integers = unpack("C*", $encrypted_data);
```

and comparing with `C#` this byte array `byte[] iv = buffer.Take(16).ToArray();` , they are equals, then I expect, that I am using wrongly `openssl_decrypt` method

Comment: You seem to use a 16 bytes key in the C# code. Then you have to use aes-128-cbc in the PHP code (otherwise PHP automatically pads with 0x00 values to 32 bytes, so that different keys are used).

Comment: @Topaco, I have tried `$cipher = "aes-128-cbc";` but unlucky. Also I didn't understand a bit, if I use OPENSSL_RAW_DATA then I can not encode $data, correct?

Comment: Works on my machine (using your C# and PHP code and the suggested changes). How many bytes does your key have?

Comment: `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` must be set if you pass the raw data, which you do (since you perform a Base64 decoding before decryption).

Comment: @Topaco 32 bytes, ok thx, then I understood correctly about OPENSSL_RAW_DATA

Comment: For a 32 bytes key, aes-256-cbc is correct. As I said, on my machine a ciphertext created with the C# code can be decrypted with the PHP code, provided the changes have been considered. If you still have problems you should post test data: plaintext, test key and ciphertext.

Comment: it's worked!!! Before I forgot to do hex2bin(key), because key should be in binary. And then I switched back to aes-256-cbc.

Comment: @Topaco thanks a lot for your time and help. You are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I was having an issue how to correct retrieve 16 first bytes from string, because I thought I was doing it incorrectly. Thanks from @Ilia Yatsenko for his answer:

```
$first16Bytes = substr($str, 0, 16);
```

But then I have realised, that I am wrongly using `openssl_decrypt()` method. After having conversation in comments, particularly with @Topaco, we found what was the proble. Here is working code:

```
$cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
$encryption_key = hex2bin(env("ENCRYPTION_KEY"));
$base64decoded = base64_decode($encrypted_data, true);
$iv = substr($base64decoded, 0, 16);
$data = substr($base64decoded, 16, strlen($base64decoded) - 16);
$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($data, $cipher, $encryption_key, 
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
dd($decrypted_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In php any string is just a sequence of bytes, so you can work with it directly, e.g. access single byte by its index, or use `substr` to trim some amount of bytes. Example:

```
$str = 'some text or binary data received by http';
$first16Bytes = substr($str, 0, 16);
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `substr` returns `false`? Maybe some of previous steps returned empty string? Try to var_dump result after each step and see what went wrong.

Comment: Also substr may return false when the total length of string is less than given offset.

Comment: No, openssl_decrypt returns false

Comment: So the problem is not in getting first 16 bytes, right?

Comment: @Aleksandrs - Code in a comment is hard to read and therefore better posted in the question. `openssl_decrypt()` expects Base64 encoded data by default. Thus, Base64 encode `$data` or set `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` as 4th parameter in `openssl_decrypt()`.

Comment: @IliaYatsenko, yes seems the problem is passing wrong data to `openssl_decrypt` method.

Comment: @Topaco, I have added code to my post, I have tried to pass OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, not working, as well as `base64_encode($data)` as first param of `openssl_decrypt`

Comment: @IliaYatsenko, Thanks for your answer, in the beginning I thought that the problem was in getting correctly 16 first bytes, but as we see not. But your answer is half way to resolve my issue. Thanks.